# Login-AzureRmAccount unattended

Tags: powershell, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a Powershell script to set app config setting, like this:

```
Set-AzureRMWebApp -Name $SiteName -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -AppSettings $settings
```

This script will be used by VSTS Release-Management in Azure but also by developers within their VS2015 IDE.

The PS script has a command 'Login-AzureRmAccount' which will show a popup on their local dev machine, that's ok.

But this script is also used by Release-Management using a PS task, but I get an error when kicking off a release: 
**'Showing a modal dialog box or form when the application is not running in UserInteractive mode is not a valid operation'**.

How can I prevent the dialog in VSTS only ?

(note that the Set-AzureRMWebApp seems to works fine, but only the prevention of the dialog results in the task error).

Comment: Please see `Authenticating using a service principal` section here: https://blogs.endjin.com/2016/01/azure-resource-manager-authentication-from-a-powershell-script/. HTH.

Comment: If you're using a "Azure Powershell script" Task, the process is already authenticated when your script runs. I guess you just need to figure out how to skip `Login-AzureRmAccount`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the fix that works:

```
if ([Environment]::UserInteractive -and
        !([Environment]::GetCommandLineArgs() |? {$_ -ilike '-NonI*'}))
{
    Login-AzureRmAccount
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to parameterise the login section of your script so this only runs if it isn't being ran by a dev. When devs run it, call it with a switch to say so.

Then you can do something like

```
$secret = yourServicePrincipalKey
$azureApplicationId = yourServicePrincipalID
if (!switch)
{
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secret -AsPlainText -Force
$creds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($azureApplicationId, $password)
$access = Login-AzureRmAccount -Credential $creds -ServicePrincipal -TenantId $tenantId
}
```

You can see that Login-AzureRmAccount has the -servicePrincipal switch enabled